# Boost serial_port memory leak

Tags: boost-asio

Visual Leak Detector observes a memory leak (a minor 40 bytes) in the following code..

```
...
void simulatememoryleak(){
        boost::asio::io_service m_IOService;
        boost::asio::serial_port m_SerialPort( m_IOService, "COM21" );;

        m_SerialPort.cancel();
        m_SerialPort.close();
        m_IOService.stop();
        m_IOService.reset();
}
..
```

Can anyone suggest why this is?

I have also posted questions to the VLD and boost communities..

Comment: a VLD log with the leak could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On my linux box it only leaks when there is no permission to open the serial port (in which case it aborts with an exception).

Here's a valgrind of the working run ¹:

```
$ sudo valgrind --leak-check=full ./test 
==21281== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==21281== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==21281== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==21281== Command: ./test
==21281== 
==21281== 
==21281== HEAP SUMMARY:
==21281==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==21281==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 851 bytes allocated
==21281== 
==21281== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==21281== 
==21281== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==21281== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

When not running as root I get

```
==21286==      possibly lost: 331 bytes in 4 blocks
==21286==    still reachable: 664 bytes in 8 blocks
```

¹ using `/dev/ttyS0` or similar

Comment: The port is being opened successfully, and this leak occurs for me.. It might be an issue with VLD rather than boost, or it might be a windows specific problem.